# How to get all selected indexes in AlertDialog multiChoiceItems

Tags: android, list, listener, android-alertdialog

I am having some trouble trying to figure this out.  What i have is a multichoice alert dialog and what i want to do is when the positive button is pressed, I want a task to be performed on the checked indexes.  How can i go about doing that?

This is where I am up to...

```
dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(list, null, null);
dialog.setPositiveButton("Okay", null);
```

SUMMARY: How can i get all of the checked indexes from the AlertDialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach I took was to declare a `final Boolean []` to store the state of the items and then when I called the `setMultiChoiceItems` method I provided a `DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener` which set the state for each item in this array when it changed. Then when the positive button was clicked, I could refer to this array from the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.

So for example (copied and slightly obfuscated from some of my code):

```
    final int aIndex = 0;
    final int bIndex = 1;
    final int cIndex = 2;
    final int dIndex = 3;

    final CharSequence[] items = {
            context.getString(R.string.string_share_include_a),
            context.getString(R.string.string_share_include_b),
            context.getString(R.string.string_share_include_c),
            context.getString(R.string.string_share_include_d) };

    final Boolean[] state = new Boolean[4];
    state[aIndex] = true;
    state[bIndex] = true;
    state[cIndex] = true;
    state[dIndex] = false;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.string_share_dialog_title);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, new boolean[] { true, true, true,
            false }, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                boolean isChecked) {
            state[which] = isChecked;
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.string_share_ok,
            new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Utilities.shareStuff(
                            state[aIndex],
                            state[bIndex],
                            state[cIndex],
                            state[dIndex]);
                }
            });
```